# How to implement paid apps, without using microsoft's payment platform?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

Microsoft offers some ways for selling our apps, but takes 30% and also there is a long time to come the money to my account.

Is there any other practical way for implementing a paid app, PayPal or something else? any reference is useful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you own the server to your applications - then there's nothing stopping you from charging for access to these web services. For example - where I work we sell access to our platform that is a corporate gateway. Users need an activation code when they start the app and a login and password to login and receive their content.

If you're okay with maintaining your own application authorization servers, you can easily add a state to your application that will verify with a server if they're OK to use it. Once they have, the application won't bother them anymore. The server software can be anything - probably a web stack. Then you can use any payment and eCommerence software you want to recieve the payment via your website.

Keep in mind - this is a giant hoop for some of your users, as they're going to need to login to your site and make a manual purchase. **Heck, it's not verified either that they're getting 100% what they expect. So unless you have a really good reason to bypass the market, you probably shouldn't.**

Answer (score 1):

Keep one thing in mind... the cost of selling the app is one thing. It usually is if you feel your app is worthy enough that someone will pay a fee to download it.

The 30% cut to Microsoft is the same with other similiar platforms and an industry standard. Consider it a fee to be able to access the millions of Windows Mobile users to your application.

If you want to get optimum money, sure go ahead and use a server and have people sign up for a service and pay a fee but remember your app has to warrant a fee that you are charging wether one time or monthly. Also remember if the app is returned disputed by the PayPal user you run the risk of a charge back for which you will have to spend time answering. In the case of a Microsoft charge back you just get the money debited but you are not responsible to answer for the chargeback. Looking to bypass the 30% fee is very short sighted IMHO. Its not worth it to deal with PayPal.